# Android Studio doesn't find drawables during the build

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to build my project the ide gives me this error

AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Then it says it can't find any drawables in the folders and gives me this error for all of them

error: resource drawable/round_corner_valid (aka terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_valid) not found.

[image: after I try to build the project]

EDIT: this is the new output

> Android resource linking failed Output: 
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:33:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_valid (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_valid) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:42:
>   error: resource drawable/search_ (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/search_) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\element_near_list.xml:21:
>   error: resource drawable/style_element_near_list (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/style_element_near_list) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_home.xml:35:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_valid (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_valid) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_home.xml:44:
>   error: resource drawable/search_ (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/search_) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_map.xml:16:
>   error: resource drawable/user_position (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/user_position) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_option.xml:13:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_option.xml:22:
>   error: resource drawable/user (aka terzad.com.trinus:drawable/user)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_option.xml:42:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\itinerary_element_place.xml:23:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\list_item_generic.xml:15:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\list_item_generic.xml:23:
>   error: resource drawable/corner_img (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/corner_img) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\list_item_generic.xml:28:
>   error: resource drawable/colosseum (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/colosseum) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\nearest_place.xml:6:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\section_cost_place.xml:8:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\section_images_place.xml:8:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\section_info_place.xml:8:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\section_other.xml:8:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\section_place.xml:8:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>   C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\src\main\res\layout\section_rating_place.xml:8:
>   error: resource drawable/round_corner_section (aka
>   terzad.com.trinus:drawable/round_corner_section) not found.
>
> Command:
>   C:\Users\massi.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-windows.jar\965937a3c1ba8a6e7b389be4e8c3d0f5\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           C:\Users\massi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           terzad.com.trinus\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha17-4804415-windows Daemon #0

EDIT 2
[image: structure of your res/ folder]

Comment: Where is the drawable round_corner_valid defined? Is it your own resource or does it come from a library? Also, which version of android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: The drawable "round_corner_valid" is my own resource. I am using the 4.4

Comment: 4.4 is the version of gradle, what about the version of android gradle plugin? You can tell by checking your build.gradle file and seeing the version name in `com.android.tools.build:gradle:<version is here>`. Also, what folder is the resource round_corner_valid located in?

Comment: Sorry, the version of android gradle plugin is 3.2.0-alpha17. The resource is located in drawable folder. After I made the

Comment: Now the Ide says " Android resource linking failed ...." and then shows me what resources and where they are called

Comment: That's interesting, can you please also post the contents of C:\Users\massi\Documents\Backup\Trinus\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt ?

Comment: Here: 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxh8ycpj5fc6fAquwMS8arZ78dNSupHfLIMC_1Zc6C8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: this file is a list of compiled resources passed to AAPT2 for linking. None of the resources for which you're getting errors (like round_corner_valid or style_element_near_list) seem to exist. They are not compiled and passed for linking. Can you post the structure of your res/ folder? It looks like some of your files are not being picked up for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `drawable/round_corner_valid` is available under `drawable` and not under `drawable-v24` (or something similar).

Comment: It's under the "drawable" folder